# How to get absolute path of file in Android

Tags: java, android

If I have two files, MainActivity and FileA. Both are in the same directory. FileA is already created, it's not being created on the fly. How do I get the absolute path of FileA from inside MainActivity?

```
class MainActivity {

    private void getPath() {
      // String path = absolute path of FileA
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. That is a file on the filesystem of your development machine. It is not a file on the filesystem of the device.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get the path of anything within the `src` directory...

in best case, you could get a path for the `assets` and `res/raw` resources.

Comment: how would I get the path of FileA if I put it in either assets or res/raw?

Comment: `Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packagename/raw/filename");` (without the suffix).